# How can I give an RxJS observable pipe access to the original observable's emission AND the pipe's previous emission?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2, rxjs-pipeable-operators, immer.js

I have an RxJS Observable that emits a series of changes to an underlying data structure—specifically, [snapshotChanges() from an AngularFirestoreCollection](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges).

- I'm currently mapping this to an array of plain JavaScript objects for consumption by my app.
- This array is not protected in any way, and consuming code could accidentally modify this structure.
- The entire array is rebuilt whenever the underlying data source emits, even if only one (or sometimes no) item in the array has actually changed.
- Because of this, all references change each time, making change detection harder than it needs to be—and really slowing down my app.

What I want to do instead is use [Immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) to maintain an immutable structure, such that unchanged data is structurally shared with the “new” array.

What I can't work out is how to `pipe()` off the `snapshotChanges()` observable such that the pipe gets access to the previously emitted immutable data (or a first-time default) **in addition to** the latest `snapshotChanges()` output.

In code, what I basically already have is this:

```
const docToObject = (doc) => { /* change document to fresh plain object every time */ };
const mappedData$ = snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes => changes.map(change => docToObject(change.payload.doc)),
    tap(array => console.log('mutable array:', array)),
);
```

and I'm essentially looking for something like this, where I don't know what `XXX(...)` should be:

```
const newImmutableObject = (changes, old) => {
  // new immutable structure from old one + changes, structurally sharing as much as
  // possible
};
const mappedData$ = snapshotChanges().pipe(

// ==================================================================================
    XXX(...), // missing ingredient to combine snapshotChanges and previously emitted
              // value, or default to []
// ==================================================================================

    map(([snapshotChanges, prevImmutableOutput]) => newImmutableOutput(...)),
    tap(array => console.log('IMMUTABLE ARRAY with shared structure:', array)),
);
```

I feel like [the `expand` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html) is close to what I need, but it seems to only pass the previously emitted value in on subsequent runs, whereas I also need the newly emitted `snapshotChanges`.

**Given an RxJS Observable pipe, how can I operate on this Observable's emissions while also having access to the pipe's previous emission?**

Comment: [`scan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) seems to be what you are looking for: `snapshotChanges().pipe(scan((prev, changes) => newImmutableObject(changes, prev), []))`

Comment: Thank you—this is exactly what I was looking for (I was so close!).  [The learn-rxjs page for `scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) even says “You can create [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)-like state management with scan!”  [Example 2: Accumulating an object](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html#example-2-accumulating-an-object) shows almost precisely what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement I would suggest to use `scan` operator which can track all previous state and new state.

```
const newImmutableObject = (changes, old) => {
  // new immutable structure from old one + changes, structurally sharing as much as
  // possible
};
 const mappedData$ = snapshotChanges().pipe(
 scan((acc, current) => [...acc, current], []), //<-- scan is used here
 map(([snapshotChanges, prevImmutableOutput]) => newImmutableOutput(...)),
    tap(array => console.log('IMMUTABLE ARRAY with shared structure:', array)),
);
```

Comment: Thank you.  In fact, with the `scan` operator I don't actually need the subsequent `map` operator after all.