# How to add the latest emission to the already emitted set, creating a new observable containing both?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an observable that emits values every now and then. At the consumer, I get the latest value but I'd like to get said value as a part of (and including) the previously emitted ones. I get that I need to use [`switchMap`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-umfz7o?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) to cancel the current observable and return a new one that contains all the historical emissions, adhering the latest one.

Starting with the identity mapping below, what operator should I use? I have tried with a bunch of different ones but didn't really see a methodical way to narrow down the set of available choices.

```
const source = interval(3000);
const transform = source.pipe(switchMap(_ => of(_)));
const subscribe = transform.subscribe(val =>
  console.log("unchanged: " + val)
);
```

At the moment, the emitted values result a sequence *0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...* but I'd like it to conserve the previously emitted values and build up an array amending the latest emission to it. So the final result would become *[], [0], [0,1], [0,1,2], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3,4], ...*.

Which RxJs operator is the proper one to use in `switchMap(...)`? Is there a better choice than `switchMap(...)`? Is the approach with `pipe(...)` appropriate at all?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-umfz7o?file=index.ts)

I thought I found a [pre-existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235649/how-can-i-give-an-rxjs-observable-pipe-access-to-the-original-observables-emiss) but that's not really what I'm helped by.

**Edit**

Based on the answers, I sense that `scan` or `scanMap` might be an appropriate choice. I didn't realize it when I was checking the docs for it, which might be due to my confusion and lack of certainty.

I have the impression that creating a new observable for each new emitted value is to be preferred but I can't tell how that would affect the performance etc. as I can't see pros and cons of using `scan` versus `switchScan`.

Comment: You actually don't need `switchMap()` unless you are calling another observable to get your value.  Since you seem to just want to accumulate all emissions, `scan` is what you need as mentioned below by @HTN

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify *"not really what I'm helped by"* - what did you actually *do*, and with what result? Also what's `scanMap`? If by "new observable for each new emitted value" you're referring to the `of` in martin's answer then note that's totally pointless unless you need to resolve an observable for each value emitted from the scan (in this case you don't appear to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could use `switchScan` which is a new operator since RxJS 7 (partly implemented by me :)) but it really depends on what exactly you want to do.

```
const source = interval(500);
const transform = source.pipe(
  switchScan((acc, num) => of([...acc, num]), []),
);
```

For most cases, even [`mergeScan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeScan) does the job and even [`scan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) if there's no requirement to return an observable. At the moment, only RxJs 6 is publicly documented making the plain and merge versions more recognizable.

```
const source = interval(500);
const transform = source.pipe(
  mergeScan((acc, num) => of([...acc, num]), []),
);
```

Live demo for [`scan`, `mergeScan` and `switchScan`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qegyfz?file=index.ts). Original author's [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-1n81wa?devtoolsheight=60) (for `switchScan` only).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think I got it now. Both `switch` and `merge` produce a fixed number of "echos" based on each incoming signal. The difference is that if the incoming elements are faster than emission of the subsequence is finished, the echoed are cancelled or superimposed. So if I only need to convert (or accumulate) an incoming signal to a single subsignal, there's... *totally no point* using other than `map` (or `scan`). Please, please, pretty please with cherry on top, please do tell me that I got it right. I've never wanted to hear *yes* as much as right now, except first time I got laid.

Comment: @KonradViltersten that's about right. `scan` works fine if you're just returning a value from the accumulator. You need `mergeScan` if you're returning an *observable* of the value from the accumulator (using `of` in this case), it *merges* the emitted values into the outer observable. `switchScan` then adds cancellation of an in-flight observable if its result would be invalidated by a new value arriving from upstream.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's close enough to *yes* in my opinion. I'm good and got educated rather well. I want to have it on the record that my progress in this, rather complex, regard was to large extent dependent on your patience and attentiveness, which I warmly appreciate. The last remark on creating a new observable did the final trick for me. I owe you a pizza, mate. And if you're around Stockholm, you can get one today.   :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `scan` operator? https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan

```js
const source = interval(3000);
const transform = source.pipe(scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []));
const subscribe = transform.subscribe(val =>
  console.log("unchanged: " + val)
);
```

Comment: The question linked by the OP shows scan, so you’d have to assume they’d already tried it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't produce an observable, like the other one does. However, both those were needed (alongside with support from others, to get me over the top, so +1 to you too.